# 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer in Bayes optimization

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, lstm, bayesian

I understand that when 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer some variable is seen as decimal instead of integer. The problem is I can`t find which one, since the type of those I use is integer. The problem occurs when I try to do Bayesian optimization for LSTM network.
Part of my code  in the function for generating the model :

```
def gen_model(num_of_lstm,num_of_neurons):

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 64, input_shape = [X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]]))
for i in range(num_of_lstm):
    model.add(LSTM(units = num_of_neurons))
    print("Type of layer num: \n")
    print(type(num_of_lstm))
    print("Type of neurons num: \n")
    print(type(num_of_neurons))


model.add(Dense(1))


optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)

#compile the model so it can be trained.
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss='mse')
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3,patience=100, verbose=0, mode='auto', restore_best_weights=True)

    
model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data=(X_test,y_test),callbacks=[monitor],verbose=0,epochs=1000)
pred = model.predict(X_test)

errors = pred - y_test
mse = np.square(errors).mean()
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
return (-mse)
```

Part of the code where the optimization is initialized:

```
pbounds = {'num_of_lstm':(1,6), 
       'num_of_neurons':(32,1024)
      }
optimizer = BayesianOptimization(
f=gen_model,
pbounds=pbounds,
verbose=2,  # verbose = 1 prints only when a maximum 
# is observed, verbose = 0 is silent
random_state=1
```

)

```
optimizer.maximize()
```

This is the error at the end when I run optimizer.maximize()

```
<ipython-input-107-26b522b69e70> in gen_model(num_of_lstm, num_of_neurons)
      3     model = Sequential()
      4     model.add(LSTM(units = 64, input_shape = [X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]]))
      5     for i in range(num_of_lstm):
      6         model.add(LSTM(units = num_of_neurons))
      7         print("Type of layer num: \n")

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I can`t find how the optimizer_maximize() work. How the values from pbounds are taken, how it operates with them. As for the examples I have seen, I thought that it should check for number of lstm layers between 1 and 6 ( will check 1 layer, 2 layers, etc until 6 layers). Where am I doing worng?

Comment: I think it's having problems with the argument to the `range` function.  That has to be a real integer value, not a float of any sort.,  `num_of_lstm`

Comment: @hpaulj if I check the type of the value, it is integer, both num_of_lstm and num_of_neurons. That`s why I am confused.

Comment: A full traceback might help.  Usually the error line is clearly marked.

Comment: What's the purpose of this range loop?  Is the use of tuples for pbounds approved by the optimizer docs?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is consistent with what `range` produces.

```
In [15]: range(7.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-15-f9ae3bee34e5>", line 1, in <module>
    range(7.0)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

In [16]: range(np.array([1.2])[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-16-d35255ed6111>", line 1, in <module>
    range(np.array([1.2])[0])
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

There are other functions that expect integer arguments (usually some parameter where a float doesn't make sense), but often the error message is different. The exact match strongly suggests this is the problem line.

I can't help further because I don't see the place that calls `gen_model` and defines its arguments.

Comment: gen_model is called bellow, when I performa bayesian optimization. In this piece of code 
pbounds = {'num_of_lstm':(1,6), 
       'num_of_neurons':(32,1024)
      }
optimizer = BayesianOptimization(
f=gen_model,
pbounds=pbounds,
verbose=2,  # verbose = 1 prints only when a maximum 
# is observed, verbose = 0 is silent
random_state=1 ) optimizer.maximize()